# jQuery show and z-index

Tags: jquery, html, hide, z-index, show

The following code is not working as expecting :

**EDIT: 

Sorry for the misunderstanding, I simplified too much my issue, here is the real issue I'm facing: http://jsfiddle.net/bc6hr/**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1">div 1</div>
<div id="2">div 2</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
}
#1 {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
$("div").hide();
$("#1").show();
$("#2").show();
```

I must be missing something, because from what I know, this code should be displaying "div 1" fading to "div 2", but it is actually rendering "div 2" from the start.
How could I make it displaying "div 1" knowing that I must hide all divs before? I thought using `z-index` was a good try, but maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `id` attribute is invalid. You cannot start an id with number.

Updated your [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBWcM/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that's not really my issue, see the edit. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

<del>The problem is, that `1` and `2` are not valid IDs. Therefore either jQuery or the CSS parser doesn't recognize the element. Use `a` and `b` instead and see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/mBWcM/1/</del>

The problem is, that when you call the z-index change in JavaScript, the divs are not even there (the code lives in the `head` element and is immediately executed). See the [fiddler page's source](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bc6hr/show/light/).

Work around: Embrace everything in the "Start, when DOM is ready" construct:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   // your code here
});
```

*Edit:* Actually, I think it's a jsFiddle issue. When I re-load the page once or twice, it happens, that "div1" remains visible, the other times, it's "div2". I just saw, that jsFiddle indead wraps the code in a `window.onload` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for editing your reply.  Even reloading does not help for me, and of course I do wrap it in a ready() in my actual page. I am still experiencing the issue =/ Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Change your IDs to valid ones ... (*[no starting with numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)*)

example http://jsfiddle.net/mBWcM/3/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the id cannot start with a number.  When the div's ids are changed to d1 and d2, they work:

http://jsfiddle.net/mBWcM/4/